# How to avoid "The file format is not supported." when sending problematic JPGs from WhatsApp upon selection from gallery?

Tags: whatsapp-messenger, tablet, photos, bugs, lenovo-yoga

**Device description:**

- Hardware: LenovoPad YOGA Table 2-1050L
- Operating System: Android 5.0.1
- Application: WhatsApp both 2.20.189 and 2.20.193.10 (newest from web, unavailable through google play)

**Problematic, fine JPGs and exif:**

- [problematic1.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2rzrzaztje2jnad/problematic1.JPG)
- [problematic2.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2k3bwoj5hu0l9je/problematic2.JPG)
- [fine1.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/knb90jxu6sc3fae/fine1.JPG)
- [fine2.jpg](https://www.dropbox.com/s/2cpv28pykynokb2/fine2.JPG)
- [directory with photos and '"exiftool(-k).exe" -a -u -g1 -w txt' output](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/gv2ifd61qxmm0x7/AAA6IJR9aDjtHL5ZgvaNKMNLa)

**Reproduction steps:**

1. On WhatsApp chat screen - Add Attachment
2. On Attachment source selection - Gallery
3. In Gallery - select specific problematic JPG
4. Gallery redirects to "Add a caption" screen which redirects back to Gallery/Chat (depending on Gallery) after few seconds (<3 s).
5. Some galleries show "The file format is not supported." in a Toast UI Element after redirection.

**Taken steps to mitigate:**

- reinstall android from 4.x.x to 5.0.1
- reinstall WhatsApp, clear data & cache, restore backup
- upgrade to newest WhatsApp version not yet made available through Google Play from offial site
- sending from sharing options of different galleries fails after selecting recipient in WhatsApp on Step 4)

**Observations:**

- sending as a Document (Step 2. - Document) works
- sending from Samsung Galaxy S5, Android 6.0.1, WhatsApp 2.20.189 to mentioned device works
- sending, resolution scaled down to >78% fails BUT to <=78% works WHILE taking a photo with much higher resolution and sending it works
- sending, with minor change from built in gallery editor (which also scales down resolution), works
- sending different JPG taken in a same day with the same camera with higher resolution works
- sending photo taken by camera works
- sending from external/internal storage fails

**Example solution:**

- process affected JPGs in a batch processing software with minimal impact on quality (do not want to scale down to <=78%)
- software fix

Please help. My next step would be attaching debugger or scaling down every photo >_<.